# scala type parameterization confusion

Tags: scala, parameterization

Consider the following example

```
abstract class Lookup(val code:String,val description:String)

class USState(code:String, description:String, val area:Symbol)
  extends Lookup(code,description)

class Country(code:String, description:String, val postCode:String)
  extends Lookup(code,description)

class HtmlLookupSelect(data:List[Lookup]) {
  def render( valueMaker:(Lookup) => String ) =
    data.map( (l) => valueMaker(l) )
}

val countries = List(
  new Country("US","United States","USA"),
  new Country("UK","Unites Kingdom","UK"),
  new Country("CA","Canada","CAN"))

def lookupValue(l:Lookup) = l.description
def countryValue(c:Country) = c.description + "(" + c.postCode + ")"

val selector = new HtmlLookupSelect(countries) //Doesn't throw an error
selector.render(countryValue) //Throws an error
```

`HtmlLookupSelect` expects a list of Lookup objects as constructor parameter. While creating a HtmlLookupSelect object, a list of county objects are passed to it and the compiler doesn't throw an error since it recognizes `Country` as a subclass of `Lookup`

But in the next line, when I try to invoke a method with Country as the parameter type(instead of the expected Lookup), I get a `Type mismatch` error. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`countryValue` is a function from `Country` to `String` (actually a method that gets eta-expanded into a function, but not relevant now), i.e. a `Function1[Country, String]`.

`render` expects a `Function1[Lookup, String]`.

So the question we want to answer is

> Given `Country` is a subtype of `Lookup`
>
> is `Function1[Country, String]` a subtype of `Function1[Lookup, String]`?

In order to answer that, let's look at the definition of `Function1`:

```
trait Function1[-T1, +R] extends AnyRef
```

See the `-T1`? That's the input parameter and the `-` means that `Function1` is **contravariant** in its input parameter and **covariant** in its output parameter.

So, if `A <: B` (where `<:` is the subtype relation) and `R <: S`
then

```
Function1[B, R] <: Function[A, S]
```

In your example, `Country <: Lookup` so

```
Function1[Country, String] </: Function[Lookup, String]
```

---

In other words a function is a subtype of another when it promises no less (co-variant return type) and it requires no more (contra-variant input type).

For example: a function that takes an `Animal` and returns an `Apple` can be used whenever a function that takes a `Dog` and returns a `Fruit` is required. More formally

```
Dog <: Animal
Fruit <: Apple
Function1[Animal, Apple] <: Function1[Dog, Fruit]
```

but the opposite isn't true: if your function handles dogs and returns any fruit, it surely can't be used to handle any animal and return an apple.